# Change style with Ionic2

Tags: typescript, sass, ionic2

I need your support with ionic2. The problem is the sass style has not effect on the view in this code:

```css
$verde : #89ce4b;
$amarillo : #ece04e;
$rojo : #f15959;
$gris : #aaa;

ion-icon[name="checkmark-circle"]{color:$verde;}
ion-icon[name="close-circle"] {color:$rojo;}
ion-icon[name="alert"] {color:$amarillo;}
ion-icon[name="arrow-dropright-circle"] {color:$gris;}
```

```html
<ion-list *ngFor="let insp of Lista">
   <button ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{insp.desc}}   
    <ion-icon name="{{insp.icono}}"></ion-icon>
    </ion-label>
   </button>
</ion-list>
```

For example , if the  `"insp.icono" = "checkmark-circle"`, it must be `"$verde" = #89ce4b`. But the icon always shown with the default color (grey). What Can I do?

Comment: You should add `!important` after each style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic attaches a different attribute when you bind the icon using data binding like you are.

You need to update your scss to use ng-reflect-name instead of name.

Example:

```
ion-icon[ng-reflect-name="heart"] {
  color: green;
}
```